# ASP.Net Forms. Add Multiple Telephone Numbers to a Contact without Page Postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms

I am working on a contact management system using ASP.Net 3.5 / 4.0 Forms.

I would like to develop a feature similar to what 37Signals use in Highrise.

I wonder could you help me work out how Highrise do this feature please?

When editing a Contact they allow the user to add multiple telephone numbers to the Contact details. If there is a telephone number already then beneath that number there is a link to 'Add a phone' which then automatically opens a sub-form for the user to enter a new number and select a type from a drop down list.

After the user has added all the telephone numbers they then click 'Save' which saves all the updates to the database.

How do they do that?  I assume they're using AJAX or jQuery or similar since there is no page postback.

I would like to do something similar using ASP.Net Forms.

I've searched Google for code snippets but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards

Walter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly they did it, but it's a pretty common technique these days. I would suggest using a combination of jQuery and MS AJAX.

Use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to show the popup dialog to the user. Inside of the dialog, use an UpdatePanel so when the user clicks the save button, it's all asynchronous.

Here's a really good guide to get you started:
http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html